# Run students code safely with node js

Tags: node.js

I'm making testing system to test students code. System will run pascal and c++ progams, write in stdin and read output from stdout. Also that code should run safely(without access to file system, internet connection, etc). If there is a module(or anything else) which do it?

Comment: Node.js is a JavaScript runtime environment. It does not execute Pascal or C++.

Comment: @FelixKling node js can have modules written in c. Also something like docker container (but executing code safely) would be great.

Comment: *"node js can have modules written in c"* Yes, but Node.js is still a runtime environment for JavaScript. If you want to execute arbitrary Pascal and C++ programs, you need a Pascal runtime and and C++ compiler.

Comment: @FelixKling Can module simply wrap api of a daughter process?

Comment: You could use `exec` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html to run whatever you want. You can use stdin and stdout with it.

Comment: @FelixKling I hoped that there is a module which can do it instead of me. Looks like I have to write such module by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `exec` and set your file system permissions accordingly you can achieve what you want. It is the same as you would not want people access your back-end code, but your public folder only.